# Active pursuits (outdoor pursuits)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, phrase-request

I am trying to explain what I enjoy doing in my free time

I cannot find a proper phrase to express this.

I want to cover multiple types of activities.

In this case I want to say that I like to swimming, working out, playing football, camping, riding a bicycle, fishing .....

I have found **Active pursuits** but not sure if it is possible to use it.

Here are some sentences where I am want to use this phrase.

1. Besides my work I enjoy spending my time working out, as well as any other active pursuit.
2. In my spare time I am working out and spend time in active pursuits.

Both of the sentences look inaccurate to me.

Please suggest the best way to express the idea, it can be quite other sentence.

Thanks

Comment: **Active pursuits** is OK - maybe a little stilted, but it's hard to find one word that covers all of working out, camping, fishing, etc.  By the way, sentence #2 should probably read "...working out and **spending** time in active pursuits."  It isn't exactly wrong the way it is now, but it reads better when *working* and *spending* are in the same form.

Comment: "My **active pursuits** include, a, b and c."  "Outside of work, I enjoy, a, b and c."  If you are making a resumé, there are many good sites/businesses that can help with that specifically.I mention this because if all you do is sports and working, you need to add in another type of activity, a charity or interest like writing or painting.

Comment: Dang, thought there would be more answers by now.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, you really helped me. So basically "Active pursuits" sounds good to a native speaker ?
Thanks for mentioning a resume, that's exactly what I am doing. 
@stangdon and @ Willow Rex  could you please post the answer with more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're into walks in the countryside, camping, mountain climbing, hiking,  etc.

> 1. Besides my work, I enjoy **[the great outdoors](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/outdoors_2)**

otherwise

> 2. When I'm not working, I do a lot of indoor and **[outdoor sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outdoor_recreation)** such as: ...

You can call any pastime activity, a **leisure pursuit**.

According to Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leisure%20pursuits%2Cactive%20pursuits&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleisure%20pursuits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactive%20pursuits%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cleisure%20pursuits%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cactive%20pursuits%3B%2Cc1), the popularity of  **leisure pursuits** (blue line) has risen significantly since the 1930s, and has dominated over *active pursuits* (red line) in the last fifty years.

[image]

**EDIT**

It seems the OP is looking for a way to group these different pursuits in a sentence or two. May I suggest the following:

1. In addition to cycling, swimming, and fishing, there is nothing I enjoy more than working out.
2. I enjoy doing a vast array of healthy outdoor activities, but I am particularly keen on working out.
3. I am a keep fit enthusiast and lover of the great outdoors, in my spare time I go  camping, mountaineering, and cycling.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but could you please suggest something to use in combination "working out", so I want to emphasize this activity

Comment: @HelloMufecayo  Why can't you add it to the list? *In addition to cycling, swimming, fishing, and camping there is nothing  I enjoy more than working out.* OR "I enjoy doing a vast array of healthy outdoor activities such as: *bla*, *bla*, *bla*..". You could sum up and say *I am a keep fit enthusiast in my spare time,  yachting, skiing, camping, mountaineering, and cycling are some of the regular activities I do.*

Comment: REALLYY AWESOME, the second variant looks great to me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could say, "I am an **outdoor enthusiast**", the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outdoor_enthusiast) of which is pretty similar to what you put in the question.